# htaccess clean url syntax converts a pipe symbol to %7C

Tags: mod-rewrite, special-characters, clean-urls

i've spent the last 10 hours to figure out what am I doing wrong but no effect so far unfortunately...

so this is my case:

```
RewriteRule ^party/(.*)$ party.php?party=$1  [L]
```

is my working rule for clean url in htaccess.
It works perfectly, but now I have  some special chars in the $_GET parameter , `*` for example is not converted but pipe symbol does into `%7C`.

I checked `party.php?party=$1` and it displays all the characters correctly, so i guess my htaccess syntax is causing the failure....

I also tried the `[NE]` flag but it doesn't work...

Any ideas anyone?
Thank you very very much!

I've also just realised that url is displayed properly in mozilla...

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)?\.testynarkotykowe.xernt.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://testynarkotykowe.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

PLUS YOU do.

```
    function sUrl() {
        $_GET = explode('/',substr(getenv('REQUEST_URI'),1)); $_pth = PTH;
        if(!empty($_pth)) {
            $pth  = explode('/',PTH);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET); $i++) if($_GET[$i] == $pth[$i]) unset($_GET[$i]);
            array_splice($_GET,0,0);
        } foreach($_GET as $k=>$v) $_GET[$k] = htmlspecialchars($v); /* SECURITY: check for addslashes */
    }
}
```

Comment: Enter any link, i.e. http://localhost/url1/url2 etc and var_export($_GET) and you would get $_GET[0] => 'url1' etc...